# Pass pointer to member function compiles in MinGW-w64 but not in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, pointer-to-member

I have a `Worker` object with a `run()` non static member function.

An object has been created:

```
Worker * worker = new Worker();
```

Doing:

```
std::thread(Worker::run, worker);
```

Compiles (an works) under MinGW-w64 (gcc 4.9.1) but under linux (gcc 5.2.1) from Ubuntu, I get the compilation error:

```
Invalid use of non-static member function
```

The code is compiled with `-std=gnu++11`

I understand that in the MinGW case, the pointer to the member function has a signature with a kind of `Worker * this` parameter, allowing to use it like a static function pointer. Why is this forbidden in the linux 5.2.1 gcc, and how should I write that?

**EDIT** : I can solve this using a lambda or by adding `&` before `Worker::run`, but the question why it is accepted or not by various gcc versions remains. Is this a MinGW or gcc 4.9.1 bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
std::thread(&Worker::run, worker);
```

**[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cDl3Dqj2YZUAJMom)**

Comment: This works, thanks. Any idea why gcc 4.9.1 accepts it without ampersand? Is this related to anything which changed in the standard?

Comment: @galinette It shouldn't work, and it also does not work on GCC 4.9.1 [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J3LAPxodlucIiEyE).

Comment: MinGW-w64 bug then? That's strange since it's a gcc port which should not affect the parser. Mistery then...

Comment: @galinette sure, that's possible